# Any help to write command lines on the Terminal (mac - Qt)

Tags: qt, terminal

can you help me a little bit with the Terminal?

i would like to use these command lines :

```
cd /path/to/Qt
./configure -static <other parameters>
make sub-src
```

so i open the Terminal, and write `cd` then i drag `QtSDK` and it shows me this path : `/Developer/Applications/Qt`

EDIT :
so i guess the 3 lines must be copied one after the other...

i wrote those lines in a row, but this time i've got no error message, nor any responses if i try to write "-help" just after `./configure` , as if it wasn't working. I'm following this tutorial from the doc : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what youre trying to do. Write a script to do it for you. her is a little bit of help.

if you type

```
pwd
```

it will return your current location. This way you can find out where you are.

```
Users/Paul/QtSDK
```

if the above is your goal,

```
pwd
```

should return

```
/Users/Paul
```

This means, to Change directory (cd), all you have to do is

```
cd QtSDK
```

This is assuming QtSDK is located in your user folder. 
you can do

```
ls
```

to find out.
The following is the output of my ls in my home directory or "/Users/cy/

```
#:~ cy$ pwd
/Users/cy
#:~ cy$ ls
Desktop     Downloads   Movies      Pictures    Sites
Documents   Library     Music       Public
```

You should also see your QtSDK folder there. 
To restart your location, go back to where it should begin. Type:

```
cd
```

with nothing else. 
this will put you back to your home folder..
Last but not least,

```
 <Other Prams>
```

should be replace with the actual prams and not to be left as you have shown in your code

PS:Capitalization is important

Comment: Thanks for your help, i edited my first post if you want to have a look, but thanks for your help, it makes more sense to me now

Comment: Cool dude. I think you got it. each line could have been entered in at a time, or all together as long as they are separated with a ";" or a line return. Learning Linux/Unix is very powerful and could help you in many areas. You're on a good path.